# When using ConfigurationBuilder and appsettings.json, is it possible to set custom property binding?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, appsettings

Pretty standard procedure for manual configuration wire up

```cs
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .Build();
```

Then I call

```
var procSettings = builder.GetSection(ProcessSettings.SectionName).Get<ProcessSettings>();
```

Some data does not load. And I know why - some properties don't match to JSON attributes. I tried to decorate it with `[JsonPropertyName("captureTrace")]` thinking that microsoft would use its own binding (`System.Text.Json.Serialization`). But no! Do they really use property name and not checking the attributes? Basically, is there a way to do it - have property name different from the JSON property name?

Max I found

```
.Get<ProcessSettings>(x => new BinderOptions().BindNonPublicProperties = true);
```

Also, in my case I have the nested class, where other classes contain groups of properties within it.

Comment: The json file was read into key-value pairs instead of json string in configuration,that's why your property won't work,just try as the answer below

Comment: @RuikaiFeng Are you saying, this is a nested dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can decorate the property with [ConfigurationKeyName]

For example:

```
public record class ProcessSettings
{
    [ConfigurationKeyName("any name")]
    public string CaptureTrace { get; set; }
}
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "MyProcessSettings": {
    "any name": "AnyValue"
  }
}
```

test:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .Build();

var setting = builder
    .GetSection("MyProcessSettings")
    .Get<ProcessSettings>();

Console.WriteLine(setting);
```

output:

```
ProcessSettings { CaptureTrace = AnyValue }
```

Comment: Great. Definitely worked!! Good technique. Thanks